# What would I have to do to program a GUI in C++ using Eclipse IDE?

Tags: c++, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin

I'd like to know what do I need to add a GUI to a C++ program. I mean having some buttons, sliders, windows, text boxes, etc but without having to use visual studio.

Is this possible? is there a plugin for eclipse that allows to program/include a GUI in my program?

Or do anybody know how can I program manually a window or a button or a slider or a text box?

I know that this would be very intensive and time consuming but I'd like to know how can I do manually this kind of GUI objects.

Comment: Just use Qt, wxWindows, Win32 or whatever API: same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9241149/212858), and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1186017/212858) ... oh, and notice that writing a GUI isn't really a function of the IDE, but of the runtime.

Comment: @Useless - Ok Thanks. I performed a search before asking but none of those suggested questions poped up and I can see that I can refer to them to meet my requirements.

Comment: np - search-fu is a skill in its own right

Comment: For people who don't understand this question, the user appears to be clear in his description to use a GUI interface, something that includes dragging and dropping, re-sizing and placing, using the mouse, while programming his project using the Eclipse IDE.  I believe the answer would be to install a GUI plug-in such as what is commonly done with Windowbuilder for Java applications.  Either it can be done for C++ while programming in Eclipse or it can't.  For people that doesn't understand it, Windowbuilder actually writes Java code from the gui.  He's trying to find this for C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this :

http://mentalissue.blogspot.se/2011/08/installing-eclipse-ide-for-c-and-qt.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Qt. http://qt-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [WxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/). It uses native APIs to provide native look and feel.