# Game design in c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks, chess

I am new to C++. I am using CodeBlock for development.

As a learning exercise I want to write chess game with UI.

Can someone help me in identifying what tool and library I would need to for showing a chess board GUI

what algorithm I need to read to implement chess rules ?

any else I need to know ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of GUI-toolkits, [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) and [Qt](https://qt-project.org/) come to mind as two. See [How do I build a GUI in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186017/how-do-i-build-a-gui-in-c) for more suggestions.

Or if you want to do the board "by-hand" then you might want to try [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/).

As for chess algorithms, it depends what you're looking for. A chess AI? A way to compute if someone is in check/checkmate? I think it might be more interesting to try and come up with your own first, *then* look around at others. Although if you just want some suggestions or reading material, then [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/347/what-is-an-accurate-way-to-evaluate-chess-positions) and [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/210/what-algorithms-and-heuristics-are-popular-in-computer-chess?rq=1) looks promising.

Comment: I want to write 2 player chess.

Comment: Well then you'll still need an algorithm to check all the pieces on the board, and the GUI stuff is still valid.

Comment: can you point to that algorithm

Comment: Please, show some effort taken in your own topic, rather than asking "can you" all the time. Browsing isn't harmful. Trust me.