# Shortest path finder C++ GUI with map

Tags: c++, user-interface

Well I am new to programming. I have made a C++ console application on VS 2012 which uses Dijkstra's algorithm to calculate the shortest path between any two cities of my country .It prints the main cities the path will go through from, the total distance and the total time it would take for a person to travel that distance via a car. Well the application is just a simple C++ console application.
What I want to do is to add a GUI to it. And especially a map, which will show the path by highlighting that specific path on it. All experience I have is on C++ console apps. And I have NO idea how I'd be doing this.

Well I can manage to do some simple GUI. But kindly tell me how would I be dealing with the map. That's the main thing which I have to do.

Comment: It is operating system specific. Perhaps consider learning [Qt](http://qt-project.org/), a cross platform graphical user interface toolkit for C++.

Comment: *"Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."* - http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186017/how-do-i-build-a-gui-in-c

Comment: You can project your map in a 2D space(just for now). You will do basic drawings of that particular graphics library you chose. You can simulate a drawing path by drawing it to the screen(just an x and y). I would suggest that try to draw something in `windows` first then go back here again if you already found a  very specific question.

Answer (score 1):

[QT](http://qt-project.org/) is a good toolkit for GUI programming. They have a tool called [QtCreator](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category%3aTools%3a%3aQtCreator) which allows you to quickly build a GUI program.

But there are a lot of things to learn when developing GUIs which would be to much for an simple answer here. Good luck!