# Changing a C++ Console application to Windows subsystem

Tags: c++, migration, subsystem

The title of the question explains pretty much the whole question. I've been programming a console application for about a week now and I want to migrate over to a GUI. Sounds simple, but I'm running into some errors. I would add them here, but it seems pretty obvious that there are some preparations I need to make to move over to GUI that I haven't made yet.

So, where do I start?

Thanks,
-P

EDIT:
LIBCMT.lib(wincrt0.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16

That's all I've got so far, but by the looks of it it may be a big problem to tackle.
And if I didn't make it clear, my objective is to change from the console subsystem to the windows subsystem.

Comment: Post your errors and code, that's the easiest way for us to debug your issue.

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more specific? For starters, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186017/how-do-i-build-a-gui-in-c

Comment: _"but it seems pretty obvious"_ - I can assure you it's not.

Comment: Fair enough. Sorry guys.

Comment: @Phixle `I've been programming a console application for about a week now`  Only a week?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah I know. Enough of the week was spent that it would be a real pain to start over from the Windows subsystem though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like WinMain is set as the entry point of your application (as a Windows subsystem app), where you probably have a main() function somewhere from your console application. Set the entry point to main() or implement WinMain to resolve the linker issue.

Comment: Oh dang. Haven't tried yet but that sounds a lot more simple than what I was expecting.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I overlooked that.

Comment: Changing the entry point will bypass all of the C and C++ runtime's initialization code which is what actually calls `main` (or `WinMain`). You'll need to implement [`WinMain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx).