# How to make a window using C++ on mac

Tags: c++, xcode

I am looking for a way to use C++ to make a window using Xcode. the reason being I have looked for ways to do this, but they all seem to be using visual basic, and seeing as I have a mac, i can not run this. If it just to difficult to make a window on Xcode, is there another program I can use, because I am hoping to later turn this into a user interface for a program...
~Regards
Mark Calhoun

Comment: Use Objective C to create the window, or switch to Qt.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I build a GUI in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186017/how-do-i-build-a-gui-in-c)

Comment: Also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits#Based_on_C.2B.2B_.28including_bindings_to_other_languages.29

Comment: If you're looking for something simple and small, then use GLUT and GLUI. You need to use OpenGL for Graphics. GLUT is for callback functions (mouse, keyboard, etc). GLUI is for GUI ( buttons, menu, etc).

Comment: I highly recommend against using GLUT and GLUI if you're coming from Visual Basic or are new to programming. OpenGL is very obtuse and not nearly as useful as the built-in OS tools for building normal apps. (If you're writing a 3D game, or a CAD program, or something like that, then by all means, use OpenGL, though.) Plus, GLUT is deprecated and not really supported anymore.

Comment: Use wxWidget to show a window...

Comment: [There's a blog post here](http://glampert.com/2012/11-29/osx-window-without-xcode-and-ib/) that does this

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may want to look into a framework that Herb Sutter actually mentioned at Going Native, back in 2012: http://www.openframeworks.cc

I've actually experimented with this framework in Xcode 5 and it works as advertised

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start with [Apple's "Start Developing Mac Apps Today"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/chapters/01_Introduction.html) tutorial. In particular the [Your First Mac App](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/books/RM_YourFirstApp_Mac/Articles/Introduction.html) page shows how to create a simple app with a window and some controls, and how to set that up in Xcode.