# Creating a usable program from a C++ console application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, console-application

I am currently learning a great deal of coding in Visual Studio using the c++ programming language in class. I have building console applications for quite some time and I feel that I can handle, or at least  start learning, converting these console application into actual programs others can install on their computers.

So my question is..... Whats the process of actually creating programs from console applications?

Comment: What do you mean by `creating programs from console applications`?  Do you want a [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) program?

Comment: Console application _are programs_...

Comment: Do you mean creating an installer for console applications - have a look at http://wixtoolset.org/

Comment: Generally, you don't. At best, you move your "real" code into a library that can be reused by both a command line application and an application with a GUI. But there is nothing inherently wrong or bad with command line applications and no reason they cannot be installed on other machines.

Comment: A console application *is* a program, it *is* usable and it *can* be installed on other computers. You need to reevaluate your definition of "actual program".

Comment: `converting these console application into actual programs`  The C++ compiler you're using now is a console program.  The GUI you're seeing is a wrapper around `cl.exe`, `link.exe`, `rc.exe`, etc.  -- all console programs that build your applications.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes that is what I want my end goal to be. I want to be able for users to see a clean and easy-to-use computer program rather than the cmd interface.

Comment: @Rome then you need to look into how to make a GUI.  check out this for choices: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186017/how-do-i-build-a-gui-in-c

Comment: @NathanOliver Just by overlooking the page it seems like this will be the place for me to learn where/how to get started!! :). Thanks Really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 2):

You're not very clear in your question, but I'm going to assume you mean making an executable that you and others can run. Well, when you build/debug you're actually already doing that. How else would you run your program? If you want to use it or want others to use it, you can just build it in release mode (instead of debug mode) and share that executable (.exe) file. It should be in the "Release" folder in your solution directory by default.

Comment: Forgive my lack of technical language I am not to good at memorizing the terms :( ..... That is exactly what I meant. I wanted to start editing the user interface so that when a person that isn't familiar with any software development ideas can receive the code and install it on their computer for use. I want my end result to be a file where they can install a program as an .exe and use the features of the program. I will definitely look into the "Release" folder when I get off of work and see how that goes for me.