# how to create GUI for windows

Tags: windows, user-interface

How can I create a GUI like the one given in attached image? I am on Windows 10 and I checked the Windows Samples [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples). They all lead to UI that looks like the Windows 10 UI. Please point me towards the template that can create that. If there is some sample code or boilerplate using c++, that would be really helpful.

[required GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGyqg.png)

Edit: Thanks, I have begun writing the code. I couldn't find the marked button in the image. Could you please tell which button is this in Windows Forms?

[Unknown Button : Marked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBKP8.png)

Comment: I typed "gui c++" in a search engine, and it gave me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186017/how-do-i-build-a-graphical-user-interface-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That image you shown is vb.net form design.
**VB.Net UI design is dependent on windows version because design should look like native windows UI.**

So if you create your form in vb.net and run that program in windows 10 it will look like made from/for windows 10, and for win 7 it will look different.
You can use c# also.

```
Open Visual Studio -> New Project -> Windows Forms App -> Drag & Drop buttons from left toolbar.
```

It is very easy. Just try once and you will get that.