# How to make a console program have gui

Tags: c++, user-interface

Currently I am trying to pick up C++. And I made an exponent calculator and I was wondering how you make the console program a GUI one. How does it work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I build a graphical user interface in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186017/how-do-i-build-a-graphical-user-interface-in-c)

Comment: This question is *way* too broad to answer in this site's format.  You shouldn't expect a magic solution to this.

Comment: That duplicate is literally the first google hit, and also references this is way too broad and better to go searching online. This is not a coding question, its just a research request, so try google first, something like "c++ user interface" or even just "types of c++ applications". One of the first hits for that is  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/visual-cpp-project-types?view=vs-2019

Comment: In the past I have had console programs accept command line arguments that when the proper options were used can avoid the GUI.