# Writing C++ GUI Code without Visual Studio

Tags: c++, .net, user-interface, sharpdevelop, gui-designer

I don’t have Visual Studio for C++ GUI(Because I don’t want to install such a big thing on my pc).
And I don’t have any problem with working with some really simple code editor like `Sublime Text` or `Code Blocks IDE` for console C++(of course). But the problem arises when I wanna make `GUIs` or `Graphical User Interfaces`.

I couldn’t find any resource**¹** anywhere for how to handcode**²** `GUI` without any `GUI Designer` like Visual Studio’s or Code Blocks’.

> `resource`: Any website, video etc.

> `handcode`: By this, I mean coding a `GUI` without any `GUI Designer`.

### Found the Solution

I found that I can use the graphic designer included in `SharpDevelop` IDE, which I can use for making the `GUI`, but for the intellisense, I can use `VSCode` with the C/C++ extension.

`SharpDevelop` is primarily made for `.Net`, so I can use it for `.Net` GUI also.

Comment: Have a look at MSDN, you will find some resources there. But in the long run creating UIs manually is painful.

Comment: Are you familiar with general Win32 development? Not sure if it's a question of resources or a question of knowledge.

Comment: I recommend Petzold books.

Comment: what is hancode? you want to draw it by hand or what?

Comment: I recommend using a GUI framework. Most of them are designed to work with other compilers than Visual Studio (like GCC).  Qt has a GUI Design tool, and you can use wxFrameBuilder with wxWidgets.

Comment: @Алексей Неудачин by handcode I mean making GUI without any GUI builder like the one integrated in visual studio

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev I want resources like youtube videos or websites

Comment: I have edited the question so that it becomes more clear for what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linux and g++ command for compiling cpp files.

You can choose any editor programs like notepad++ or notepad.

This question is already answered [How do I build GUI with c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186017/how-do-i-build-a-graphical-user-interface-in-c)

Comment: Sir, I know how to do that but what problem I have is  how to make GUIs(Graphical User Interfaces) with C++ **_without_** any designer that helps you to make a GUI without coding

Comment: you can creat your own .h library c++ works on low level, please upvote my answer here is example of doing GUI low Level programming https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1225196/Create-Your-Own-Kernel-In-C-2